# Table of content in ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to create a table of contents in Jupyter notebook. While I am able to create the main heading and the sub heading, I am not being able to create a sub bullet under the sub heading. 5.1 and 5.2 are appearing correctly, but 5.2.1 and 5.2.1 are not.

```
    5. [Training datasets](#train)  
       5.1 [Training dataset from original data](#original)  
       5.2 [Training dataset from sampled data](#sample)   
             5.2.1 [Upsample minority class](#upsample)   
             5.2.2 [Downsample majority class](#downsample)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, a workaround, but hopefully it helps. Please, care of indentation.

```
* 1 [Training datasets](#train)
    * 2.1 [Training dataset from original data](#original)
        * 2.1.1 [Training dataset from sampled data](#sample)
```